# $GLOBALS variable in different php version

Tags: php

In php version 5.2.17,I used $GLOBALS variable to get some information and it's work good.
but when I change php version(5.3) that this variable get value missed sometime.so i don't know the reason?

Comment: There is only [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.globals.php) in PHP as far as I know.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get info missed" in a little detail?

Comment: better don't use globals, except for testing/debugging. have never seen an use of it which can't be done better without it...

Comment: `$GLOBALS` works exactly the same in all PHP versions supporting it. Your problem is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: I find the reason that i forget used global keyword to declare.
For example: 
global $user; 
$user="Tom"; 
echo $GLOBALS["user"];

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.globals.php

This variable is used in version 4 and 5 in PHP

Answer (score -1):

Please check the setting `register_globals` in `php.ini`.

Set `register_globals = On`  to register the EGPCS variables as global variables. Otherwise, EGPCS variables will not saved into globals. It causes different behavior in your cases.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the $GLOBALS array ... See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: `register_globals` has *nothing* to do with global variables. Whatever you do, do *not* turn `register_globals` on!